# Наследование UI в qt

Tags: qt, виджет

Как обновить ui?
В конструкторе класса `mainwindow` происходит инициализация виджета `QTableWidget` с начальными значениями, как мне изменить `ui` через другой класс `connection` в данном случае при нажатии клавиш в классе `connection`, пробовал через обьект класса, ничего не происходит.

Comment: а можно код посмотреть??7

Comment: В хедере задаеться указатель на QtableWidget. В cpp файле создаеться и заполняеться обьект. tw = new QTableWidget();
    tw = ui->tableWidget; далее вызываеться функция которая принимает значение и должно добавлять его в пустую ячейку. Но в итоге полная недосягаемость - такое ощущение что все указатели умерли и достучаться вообще никак. Код добавлять не вижу смысла так как пробоал в нескольких проектах эффект один.

Comment: а эту штуку не пробывали?? QTableWidgetItem

Comment: да не тут я все понял, проблема оказалась в том что я обьект класса в котором ui неправильно вызывал сейчас буду фиксить.